# Meaning of y-axis in in Tensorboard Activation Summary

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, histogram, tensorboard, activation-function

I'm having trouble interpreting the y-axis for my activation summaries. I understand that the x-axis is values and the z-axis is the global step. I thought the y-axis is a density chart of activated nodes in the layer, but that doesn't seem right.

When I look at the histogram for my last layer (an FC layer with 10 outputs), it shows fractional values. How is that possible if there are only 10 outputs? Is it possible for only part of a node to be activated? I'm not sure what is going on here.

Thanks for any explanation!

[activation histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SR6K.png)

Comment: Averaging over the batch? What is the shape of the input to the histogram summary?

Comment: I thought it might be batch size averaging, but I have my batch size set to 1 and still see the fractional values. It's a flat layer that serves as the input into the last dense layer. So [? x 100] > [? x 10].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens in the [histogram example](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/tensorboard_histograms) too, I get a bin with 91.4 points in it for the Gaussian example. It's an artifact of smooth/soft binning, like with the [Poisson integers spread out over multiple bins](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/tensorboard_histograms#poisson_distribution).